# ram errors solved by swapping slots used by ram

Tags: memory, hardware-failure

I had 4 sticks of ram (2.5GB) working for ~3 days until on reboot POST showed RAM error. By elimination I removed the (seemingly?) 0.5GB bad RAM. Then after ~10 days I added 0.25GB of RAM, resulting in the same error.

I (seemingly?) solved the problem by first removing 1GB stick from the first slot and moving the 0.25GB RAM from last slot to first slot, rebooting to see no error, adding 1GB RAM to the last slot where the 0.25GB was. After each change ran memtest86 v4.20 to confirm.

I want to find out what is faulty if anything. I hope I will be able to use 2.5GB instead of 2.25GB without problems.

Dell Optiplex GX270 with A03 bios (Imma update to the last version, A07)
Pentium 4 2.8GHz
Various RAM sticks

Comment: What is your actual question? Nobody from superuser is going to be able to tell you definitively whether your RAM is bad.

Comment: @Kenster I'm asking for advice on my current situation.(I know I should get better hardware but this is not possible now.)

Comment: I passed memtest and got kernel panic on next boot (Lubuntu) without changing anything

Answer (score -1):

Similar problem, recurrent and intermittent, on a Thinkpad T400 with (2) 2GB PC3-8500 sticks, Micron brand, solved by swapping slots, MemTests OK.

I suspect this is caused by static electricity on or around the RAM sticks,
which gets discharged by the moisture from your hands.  My worst bout of this happened when the PC was exposed to a very hot and dry environment.

To answer your question, perhaps nothing is wrong, but maybe different chips and mobos have different tolerances to static.

To test my theory, don't move the sticks at all, but breathe air from your mouth on the sticks to discharge the static via moisture, and see if that helps.  This worked for me last time.

Comment: `but breathe air from your mouth on the sticks to discharge the static via moisture, and see if that helps.` This sounds like magic vudu. I'm not sure if this is scientifically-sound, but if anyone can indicate it is, please do so. I know humid environments do have less static electricity, and airplane wings have little 6 inch antenna things all over the back of them to "wick away" static electricity via the air passing over them, so maybe there is something to this after-all, but I don't know...